# Nginx Kerberos Authentication

Tags: nginx, solr, cloudera-cdh

The CDH Solr admin page is configured with Kerberos authentication so it cannot be access in Web browser.

I plan to use Nginx as a proxy service to act Kerberos authentication and redirect the web request to Solr admin page.

Already used the spnego module 'https://github.com/stnoonan/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module'. And set the conf file like below.

```
location / {
auth_gss on;
auth_gss_realm EXAMPLE.ORG;
auth_gss_service_name "HTTP/test.example.org";
auth_gss_keytab /etc/krb5.keytab;
return 301 xxxxx;
```

But it doesn't work. The web page still shows 403. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to perform `Troubleshooting` actions from `spnego` module manual? https://github.com/stnoonan/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module#troubleshooting

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I tried the perform those actions from document, but it does not works.

Comment: Did you check your `nginx` logs?

Comment: Yes, Configured Nginx as debug mode and searched the error log. It showed permission denied while called gss_acquire_cred() method but no NTLM error.

Comment: Then figure out what is `gss_acquire_cred` error and try to authenticate step-by-step.